# How can I pass a parameter in addTarget's action?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, action

I'm a Beginner and  not an English language family.
So my English is poor...
How can I pass a parameter into my func..

this is my code:

```
 @IBAction func newitem(sender: AnyObject) {
  ...
  ArrayofQuantityTextfield.append(UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i-1].frame.origin.x, y: ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i-1].frame.origin.y + 50, width: 65.00, height: 30.00)));
 ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].addTarget(self, action:   ***Selector("textChang(\(i))")*** 
, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
 self.view.addSubview(ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i])
 ...
**func textChange(i : Int)**{
    if ArrayofPriceTextfield[i].text!.isEmpty == false && ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].text!.isEmpty == false {
        if (Int(ArrayofPriceTextfield[i].text!) != nil) && (Int(ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].text!) != nil){
            ArrayofSubtotalLabel[i].text = "\(Int(ArrayofPriceTextfield[i].text!)! * Int(ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].text!)!)"
        } else
        { ArrayofSubtotalLabel[i].text = "plz enter number" }
    }
}
```

I use array to Dynamic Added Textfield , so I need know "i"

[test.ViewController textChang(1)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff852d0a5e0
2015-11-05 21:42:00.596 test[5364:184402] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[test.ViewController textChang(1)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff852d0a5e0'

⬆︎ error message.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Before we start answering, I'd like to advice you to: a) fix the indentation of your code and b) use local variables so that one can read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a colon

```
Selector("textChange:")
```

When adding targets to UIControl you cannot have other parameters. Byy default Selectors in target will take the sender. So your selector should be

```
func textChange(sender : UITextfield)
{

}
```

But i sense you wanted to find which textfield is selected. So for that you might want to keep an identifier as tag value to UITextfield

```
ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].tag = i;
ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].addTarget(self, action: Selector("textChange:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

In your Button Action

```
func textChange(sender : UITextfield)
   {
      if ( sender.tag == your_i_value )
      {
          //Do your stuff
      }
   }
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this the simplest and proper way is to subclass `UITextField` and add a property of `NSInteger` in this new subclass.

After this you need to use this new subclass instead of `UITextField` and set the value of `i` to that property.

Now you can access the value of `i` anywhere you want to use.

```
ArrayofQuantityTextfield[i].addTarget(self, action:  Selector("textChange:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Also you need to use `iPrabhu's` answer to put the `:` so in `textChang` method you can use the object of this new subclass.

Comment: You mean I should create a new class or override the UITextField to accomplish this problem?